# Can we ask questions which generate degree of opinion on SFSE meta?

Tags: feature-request

I have seen few closed questions which would result answers based entirely on opinions. But expert opinion will definitely help lots of newbies. A budding developer may seek opinion on

- Preferred Force.com IDE
- Best Migration Tool and approach
- Mandatory Chrome Plugins

This may increase load on moderators though.

Comment: The forum is "self-moderating" for the most part. Users of higher reputation do much of the moderation in a "queue" with the actual mods having the discretionary ability to override the outcome of voting by members who have sufficient reputation to vote on closing or reopening posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Meta is definitely not the place for this.** I think we as a community do allow some opinion based posts on the main site. But they have to be meaningful, show understanding of the issue, some research or break-down of the issue and ideally describe what kind of answer they expect.

I'm aware that is still very subjective.

Personally I would expect the following of your listed examples:

**Preferred IDE**
A possible question could be "What are the available IDE's and which one meets these criteria best ?"  Answer expectation have to be clear so that opinions are not "I like X" but become "I use X because pro: A,B,C,D, but con:E,F,G". But we're definitely not a polling site for questions as "What IDE are You using right now ?"

**Best Migration Tool and approach**
That's two things and they illustrate the broadness. "Best" for what purpose, what does OP want to achieve ? What was tried/researched and/or failed. Without described expectations a lot of answers may be written that do not answer the actual need. We don't want to waste anyone's time and efforts.

**Mandatory Chrome Plugins**
Not opposed to a canonical wiki overview of plugins or something of that nature.

Comment: These questions can fit if they're phrased correctly. Rather than asking about preferred IDE it'd be more constructive to ask about an IDE feature comparison.